# compiling abiword on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, abiword

In my flask app I often use abiword in a subprocess call. Now I am trying to migrate that application to heroku however I am running into some trouble when trying to get abiword installed

Following the approach on this website

http://theprogrammingbutler.com/blog/archives/2011/07/28/running-pdftotext-on-heroku/

does not seem to work because when I use ./configure I get the error that several packages were not found and I cant use apt-get on heroku to install them.

What can I do to create a full buildpack to add to my heroku buildpacks?

Comment: Abiword is a GUI application, right? So unless it features a "headless" or server mode, and can be compiled without any X11 dependencies, I don't see that happening on Heroko, since Heroku doesn't have an X11 server or even the necessary X11 libraries.

Comment: it may have a gui version but this is my subprocess call



subprocess.check_call('abiword -t txt -o "/tmp/%(name)s.txt" "%(filename)s"' % {
            'name': name, 'filename': filename}